# Showing selected values in a multi-select drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have a select drop-down that allows user to multi-select options. It works fine, but doesn't shows name of the selected options when multiple options are selected.

I have tried applying and using available plugins for the same, but disturbs my overall application UI. 
I am actually working on a plugin for a standard tool where I cannot use external bootstrap or external jQuery other than what is included in the tool itself

```
<select id="projectDropdown" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="value1"> option 1 </option>
 <option value="value2"> option 2 </option>
 <option value="value3"> option 3 </option>
</select>
```

The current code shows something like '1 selected' '2 selected' when values are selected from the drop-down. I am looking to show values like 'option 1, option 2' when option 1 and 2 are checked.

Comment: Try this, https://select2.org/selections

Comment: I don't understand. That basic multiple select you posted does show texts of selected options, at least on all major browsers. Please show your JS/jQuery code if your issue is displaying the texts/values elsewhere.

Comment: Please try giving a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. Thanks :)